# Trying to add to an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass along the question AND the id of the question in the first query and then with that id get that poll's options and add those to the array. Not seeing what I'm doing wronge here.

Here's the error I am getting:

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Notice
> Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$row
> Filename: models/sitemodel.php
> Line Number: 161
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Notice
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
> Filename: models/sitemodel.php
> Line Number: 161

Code:

```
function getPoll() {
    $this->db->select('site_polls.id, site_polls_questions.poll_question');
    $this->db->from('site_polls');
    $this->db->join('site_polls_questions', 'site_polls_questions.id = site_polls.site_polls_questions_id');
    $this->db->where('site_polls.status_id', 1);
    $this->db->order_by('site_polls.date_posted', 'desc');  
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $id = $query->row->id; 
    
    $this->db->select('site_polls_questions_options.poll_option');
    $this->db->from('site_polls_questions_options');
    $this->db->where('id', $id); 
    $query = $this->db->get();  
    
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can add the question of the poll into the array.

Comment: is this in Joomla? I'm not quite sure what the `$db` object does, so it's hard to say where it could be going wrong. However, you're getting notices, not errors, and generally notices are more about coding standards etc. than serious problems. Also, since your error message includes line numbers, it'd be helpful to reference the line number in your code.

Comment: If you notice I have code igniter in my tags.

Comment: I see that. Now. What is line 161?

Comment: @interstellar_coder-- that's my guess too-- which would mean that there's probably an error in the query such that it's not returning any data.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the correct usage according to the docs http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

row() is a function and not a property.

```
$id = $query->row()->id;
```

or

```
$id = $query->row(0)->id;
```

Comment: Only one issue with me doing this. It only gets the options which is good but I still need the question from the original query

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = $query->row->id;
```

Should be:

```
$id = $query->row()->id;
```

`$query->row()` is a function, not a property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->get()->first_row();
if ( !empty($query->id))
{
    $id = $query->id;
}
else
{
    return array();
}
```